# Colulmn width of "top" entries

Tags: top

The username column in the output of `top` command shows a `+` for the names that are longer than the column width. How can I increase that?

I don't see any option for that.

Comment: Yes I know that. The problem exists for `ps` command too. I really do want to see the full string of the username of a process.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Interesting; there is a way to do it. While running top, use the <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>X</kbd> interactive command to widen various fixed-width columns. Giving a parameter of 5 will, for instance, add 5 characters to the USER field, for a total of 13 characters. This ought to display the entire username for most users.

For example:

Before:

```
  PID USER      PR  NI    VIRT    RES    SHR S  %CPU %MEM     TIME+ COMMAND     
 8736 nm-open+  20   0   74744   7872   6868 S   0.3  0.0   1:28.93 openvpn
```

Press <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>X</kbd> and enter `5`:

```
width incr is 0, change to (0 default, -1 auto) 5
```

After:

```
  PID USER           PR  NI    VIRT    RES    SHR S  %CPU %MEM     TIME+ 
 8736 nm-openvpn     20   0   74744   7872   6868 S   0.4  0.0   1:29.04
```

You should resize your terminal to be wider than 80 characters before doing this, or you'll lose information.

Comment: How do I increase the width of a different field? Specifically the nTH field.

Comment: You can't, it always affects _all_ fixed-width fields. Search for "Extra-Fixed-Width" in top´s manpage for details.

Comment: Doesn't do anything on Mac OS X Ventura 13.5.1, zsh 5.9.